# Is it possible to perform donation with In-App purchase for amount the user want to donate?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

With last update Apple rejected my app, because I have donation process with PayPal through Safari. They said to implement in app mechanism. But is it possible for users to donate with In-App with amount the user want? I would like to avoid creating Purchase Items for every amount I want to use.

Comment: Did you have to provide a Restore functionality in order to not get rejected by the AppStore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, in-app purchases can only have predefined prices set in iTunes Connect. You can charge the same in-app purchase multiple times, meaning you can calculate the donation to the nearest Tier 1 multiple and repeatedly charge it, but you can’t have custom tiers. Using Apple Pay to get around this is prohibited by App Store guidelines.

Here’s how PCalc shows the various donation levels:

[image]

Comment: Also, you can set it up like Twitterrific and others where their tip jar is additive. Someone could tip $10 and then $1 twice if they wanted to tip $12. With Touch ID, it’s really easy to check out. Twitterrific also mixes in a subscription tip as well as one time tips.